# Dropzone stopped working after upgrade from "4.2.0" to "5.7.0" (using jquery "3.3.1")

Tags: javascript, dropzone

Im loading my libs like this:

```
<link href="~/lib/dropzone/dropzone.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/lib/dropzone/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

And im using my dropzone like this:

```
var CountFiles = 0;
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    $("div#myPrincipalDropzone").dropzone({ ...etc.... even another dropzones...
```

This was working before, but im not sure why i get dropzone is not defined. 
Also if i put the libs explicitellty on the Index, i receive "'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' is undefined"

tryed to add multiple Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; also change the syntax for the functions. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var CountFiles = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {

    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var Drop1 = new Dropzone("div#myPrincipalDropzone", { url: "/Article/UploadFiles",

        paramName: "file",
        maxFiles: 1,
        maxFilesize: 1200,
        maxFileHeight: 840,
        maxFileWidth: 840,
        acceptedFiles: ".png,.jpg",           
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        parallelUploads: 1,
        renameFile: function () {
            let newname = new Date().getTime() + '_' + 'Test';
            console.log("Nombre en RenameFile:" + newname);
            return newname;
        //},

        //init: function (newname) {

            this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
```

Comment: Also take in care that this is not working on IEE old versions and Microsoft Edge, it needs to apply some PollyFill to fix the symbol Iterator issue. Good Luck for the lost souls.